# jQuery / Javascript inserting attributes to an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, attr

Okay so I have this script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var content = $(".main").html();
    content = content.replace(/\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/g, function(v){
        return $('<a>').attr({
            href: "tel:"+v,
            onclick: "ga('send', 'event', 'lead', 'phone call', 'call');"
        }).html(v)[0].outerHTML;
    });

    $('.main').html(content);
});
```

which searches an area for patterns of numbers and creates a link for the number.
This part is working. However I am trying to have it also pass an "onclick" value but I can not get it to work?

Any ideas?

Comment: It's an event tracking code for Google Analytics.
I would need it to look like `onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'lead', 'phone call', 'call');"`

Answer (score 0):

You could also try and use jQuery's on method to attach a handler to the click event if that won't break the tracking:

```
return $('<a>').attr({
            href: "tel:"+v"
        })
        .on('click', function() {ga('send', 'event', 'lead', 'phone call', 'call');})
        .html(v)[0].outerHTML;
```

**Demo using .on method:**

```js
$(function() {
  var myLink = $('<a>')
    .attr('href', '#myLink')
    .on('click', function() {
      alert('Thanks for clicking me. Attach ga handler here');
      // ga(this,'send', 'event', 'lead', 'phone call', 'call');
    })
    .text("Click me");

  $('#insert-link-here').append(myLink);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>The chaining order matters. jQuery.text() returns String but jQuery.text(string) returns jQuery.</p>

<div id="insert-link-here"></div>
```

Comment: My trouble here is that I need to use Regex to find and create the links, I don't have link ID's

Comment: @scabbyjoe you already have the link in your question. After the attr() call, just attach a click event handler using the .on method. I can edit my answer to match.

Comment: I'm sorry but could you perhaps edit your answer, I'm not getting this to work.

Comment: @scabbyjoe I did :-) Check again. I added an on click jquery handler.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I still can't get it to work, it seems to break my attr function but thank you non the less!

Comment: @scabbyjoe no worries. Just make sure that your jquery chaining is also in the correct order - some methods return a string not a jquery object.